# How to Deploy an Image with the Application in Google App Engine Using Python

Tags: python, css, image, google-app-engine, deployment

Whenever I deploy my application, it deploys correctly except the backgroud image I used in main.css does not appear. If I change it to a background color, it works but background image does not work for whatever reason. When I test run by using Browse, it works but once I change the Application name in app.yaml, the Browse does not work but the Deployment works but it doesn't show the background image. How can I get the back ground image to show?

Code in main.CSS:

```
body {
  font-family: Comic Sans, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-image: url(../stylesheets/goku-wallpaper-2.jpg);
  background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
```

Code in app.yaml:

```
application: guestbooksky
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets  

- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.app

libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

Answer (score 0):

probably:

```
background-image: url(/stylesheets/goku-wallpaper-2.jpg);
```

if the image file is in the path of:

```
/stylesheets/
```

Comment: Apparently it only works if you set up a new Directory. Made a new directory named Images and put the image in there. Then, you changed the main.css to   

background-image: url(../Images/Goku-wallpaper-2.jpg);

and then the app.yaml has to be changed as well to input the handler "Images."

- url: /Images
  static_dir: Images

Comment: Depends on how you form your app dir. If it works like this keep it like this.